# How to ignore some request type in Jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, rest, express, json-web-token

I want to ignore some API URL of being checked against token authentication

I want to protect post and put methods but not get of this url

localhost:3000/api/events/

```
router.use(function(request, response) {
    var token = request.body.token || request.query.token || request.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, app.get(superSecret), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err)
                return response.json({
                    sucess: false,
                    message: "Failed token Authentication"
                });
            else {
                request.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }

        });
    } else {
        return response.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });

    }

});
```

How can I do this using jsonwebtoken in node,express

I want this to apply to only post,put,delete requests but not on get requests.

Comment: Simplest could be to put the router.get above router.use then the router.use would only apply to whatever routes you define below it in your js file

Answer (score 0):

**You can move your anonymous middleware to normal declared function and then pass it to all protected routes (you decide which route you want to protect!)**

Your code could look like:

```
function tokenProtection(request, response, next) {
    var token = request.body.token || request.query.token || request.headers['x-access-token'];
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, app.get(superSecret), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err)
                return response.json({
                    sucess: false,
                    message: "Failed token Authentication"
                });
            else {
                request.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }

        });
    } else {
        return response.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });

    }

}
```

and now your routes could look like (your decision what you want to protect):

```
router.get('/item', function(req, res) { ... }); // not protected
router.get('/item/:id', function(req, res) { ... }); // not protected
router.post(tokenProtection,'/item', function(req, res) { ... });//protected
router.put(tokenProtection,'/item', function(req, res) { ... });//protected

router.get('/book', function(req, res) { ... });// not protected
router.get('/book/:id', function(req, res) { ... });// not protected
router.post(tokenProtection,'/book', function(req, res) { ... });//protected
router.put(tokenProtection,'/book', function(req, res) { ... });//protected
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.but i didn't tried this way.but i think it is better solution than mine

Answer (score 0):

Put the routes you want to protect below your authentication route and the ones you do not want to protect can above the authentication route. Something like this,

```
    // Require what will be needed 
    var express  =  require('express'),
    User     =  require('../models/user'),
    usersRouter   =  express.Router();

    var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
    var config = require('./config'); // get our config file

    var secret = {superSecret: config.secret}; // secret variable,

    // Create a new user and return as json for POST to '/api/users'
    usersRouter.post('/', function (req, res) {
      var user = new User(req.body);
      user.save(function(){ //pre-save hook will be run before user gets saved. See user model.
        res.json({user : user, message: "Thank You for Signing Up"});

      });
    });

    usersRouter.post('/authentication_token', function(req, res){
      var password = req.body.password;
      // find the user
        User.findOne({
          email: req.body.email
        }, function(err, user) {
          //If error in finding the user throw the error
          if (err) throw err;
          //If there is no error and the user is not found.
          if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
            //if the user is found
          } else if (user) {
            // check if password matches
            user.authenticate(password, function(isMatch){
              if(isMatch){
                // if user is found and password is right
                // create a token with full user object. This is fine because password is hashed. JWT are not encrypted only encoded.
                var token = jwt.sign({email: user.email}, secret.superSecret, {
                  expiresIn: 144000 
                });
                // set the user token in the database
                user.token = token;
                user.save(function(){
                  // return the information including token as JSON
                  res.json({
                    success: true,
                    id: user._id,
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                  });
                });
              } else {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
              }
            });
          }
        });
      });

//***********************AUTHENTICATED ROUTES FOR USERS******************************

      // Return ALL the users as json to GET to '/api/users'
    usersRouter.get('/', function (req, res) {
      User.find({}, function (err, users) {
        res.json(users);
      });
    });

    // Export the controller
    module.exports = usersRouter;
```

I actually explained this yesterday itself on my blog because I was struggling to figure it out. If you are still not clear, you can check it out here, [Node API Authentication with JSON Web Tokens - the right way](http://blog.viditsaxena.com/blog//hpvz253tzmcqy4yk3k7aouzxnytxkr).

If there are other resources like in my case it was plans. Below is the code I put above all the routes for plans I wanted to authenticate.

```
    // route middleware to verify a token. This code will be put in routes before the route code is executed.
PlansController.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

  // If token is there, then decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, secret.superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
      } else {
        // if everything is good, save to incoming request for use in other routes
        req.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      }
    });

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });

  }
});
    //***********************AUTHENTICATED ROUTES FOR PLAN BELOW******************************
PlansController.get('/', function(req, res){
  Plan.find({}, function(err, plans){
  res.json(plans);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer. what if different routes are in different file and i am exporting all of them. i have user routes in user.js file and events routes in event.js file

Comment: @Rayees Check updated answer now. I included plans Routes and the authentication needed. Authentication code goes above the routes.