# How to exclude a router/api url from jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, express, json-web-token

I am using node.js express app. **jsonwebtoken** for authentication. I want to exlude some api url from the jsonwebtoken verification. below is what I have tried and my code

```
router.use('/authentication', mountAllRoutes(authenticationModule));


// route middleware to verify a token
router.use((req, res, next) => {
const r = req;
const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers.authorization;
// decode token
if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, (req.app.get('superSecret')), (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            // res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            res.status(401).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
            });
        } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            r.decoded = decoded;
            next();
            // console.log(decoded);
        }
        return {};
    });
} else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });
}
return {};
});


router.use('/test', mountAllRoutes(testModule));
router.use('/other', mountAllRoutes(otherModule));
router.use('/data', mountAllRoutes(dataModule));
```

Here I have placed routes above middleware which I dont want to protect. and I have placed after middleware which I want to protect. But it is protected which I placed above middleware. In **authenticationModule**, login and user registration api comes. so for user registration it gives response **no token provided** 
[image: postman request]

**Note:** I have refrerred this link [How-to-ignore-some-request-type-in-Jsonwebtoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890340/how-to-ignore-some-request-type-in-jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 0):

create separate route file for the API you want to exclued.

```
//Routes

  var users = require('./routes/users');
  var api = require('./routes/publicApi');
```

App.js:

// route middleware to verify a token

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
const r = req;
const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers.authorization;
// decode token
if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, (req.app.get('superSecret')), (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            // res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            res.status(401).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
            });
        } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            r.decoded = decoded;
            next();
            // console.log(decoded);
        }
        return {};
    });
} else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'No token provided.'
    });
}
return {};
});


app.use('/users', router);//will use Token Authentican
app.use('/publicApi', router);//Dont do this.
```

Comment: I have created seperate api. in that only login and registration is there. I have placed that router above middleware.  router.use('/authentication', mountAllRoutes(authenticationModule)); It has only login and registartion api.

Comment: still token asks for registration

Comment: `router.use('/authentication', mountAllRoutes(authenticationModule))` here what is `mountAllRoutes`

Comment: in that only login and registration api is there which doesn't require token protection. for login it works perfect. it wont ask protection. it generates token key which is right way but for registration it asks token not provided

Comment: it should not. Something may be missing

Comment: I have tried everything.. since 4 hour I am trying for that

Comment: As you said , you have created separate files for rotes. Than can you load then like ` var api = require('./routes/publicApi');`check.